# Display columns based on sub query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I want to display the name of department with highest SUM of salary.
I am using oracle sql and the table structure is `Dept(Deptno,Dname,Loc)` and `Emp(Empno,Ename,Job,Salary,Deptno)`.

The query I use was

```
select Dname 
from Dept 
where Deptno=
      ( select Deptno 
        from Emp 
        where rownum=1 
        group by Deptno 
        order by sum(Salary) Desc
      );
```

This gives an error:

> Right parenthesis missing.

When I run the sub-query alone, it successfully returns a `Deptno`. But with the parent query, I get the above error.

What is the problem and what can be the possible solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select dname
  from (select dname, rank() over (order by sum(salary) desc) rnk
          from dept d 
               inner join emp e 
                       on e.deptno = d.deptno
        group by dname, e.deptno
       )
 where rnk = 1;
```

note, in your example putting `where rownum=1` where you did is a huge bug. it would mean pick 1 random row and sort it (not really the highest salary row..just any old row)

my solution may get over 1 row if 2 deptartments have the same highest salary. you can use `row_number()` instead of `rank()` to just pick one if you want.